# Show that B is diagonalizable by finding a suitable factorization of B.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A = PDP^{-1}$, where P is 2 x 2 and $D = \begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\0&7 \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $B = 5I - 3A + A^2.$ Show that $B$ is diagonalizable by finding a suitable factorization of $B$.

I have substituted $A$ for $PDP^{-1}$, so $B = 5I - 3PDP^{-1} + PD^2P^{-1}$, and I have also recognized that an eigenvector $\vec{x}$ for A is an eigenvector for $B$:
$$
(5-3A + A^2)\vec{x} = (5-3\lambda + \lambda^2)\vec{x}
$$

I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking for, but this is what I have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

You found $B$ is

$$B=P(5I-3D+D^2)P^{-1}.$$

Observe $(5I-3D+D^2)$ is diagonal and you are done.